# How can I tell if Windows 7 update is deleting my kernel?

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, windows-7

I have a dual install going with windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. My window updates have been set to manual however I just find it really strange that every time I do a windows update my linux kernel goes missing and my grub loader fails at stage 2 and presents me with the grub console.

I have hunted around in my boot folder looking for my kernel (hd0, msdos2) using the grub cli and it appears not to be there. I have also setup a usb drive with ubuntu so I can try and recover my installation using boot-repair but this does not work.

I am really annoyed with this because I have to re-run the wubi installer and I keep losing my information. Is there a way to safe-guard my ubuntu against the malevolent updates from Microsoft so I don't have to keep going through this process?

My version of ubuntu is 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu

Although for best results I'd recommend this more https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_migrate_to_a_real_partition.2C_and.2BAC8-or_get_rid_of_Windows_entirely.3F
Which will direct you here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi
Maybe not removing windows entirely, but migrating to real partitions would prevent windows from touching your Ubuntu install because windows typically can't access ext partitions.

The short answer (overview) is:
Use a live CD/USB to edit your current partitions and create the needed partitions to install full Ubuntu.
Follow the instructions from the links above to get yourself migrated

Note, wubi is only supported up to Ubuntu 12.10, and is not supported by Ubuntu 13.04
You should be able to update to Ubuntu 13.04 after migrating to full partitions.
If you want to scrap your current install and start fresh with a clean full install (maybe a good idea) follow this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

If out get sick of windows entirely, backup your important data (cloud storage, external hard drive, flash drive, whatever) and then use a live CD/USB to wipe your drive and fully install Ubuntu

All of these things are the exact order I did things while on my journey from windows to Ubuntu :D

Comment: I guess what makes this creepy is that a clean shutdown is what windows update will give you right?

Comment: If you're still using 12.04 you really should move along to the next LTS 14.04. Again you'll want to follow the links I posted and decide how you would like to partition. I personally don't recommend letting windows control the boot loader (use grub). What's likely happening is windows is verifying the integrity of it's boot loader whenever you do windows updates.